# Should I use const shared_ptr<T>& or shared_ptr<T> as parameter to my lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've seen a C++11 library that receives video packets through network and in order to decide what to do with these packets it uses a lambda function like this:

```
viedoTrack->addDelegate(std::make_shared<FrameWriterInterfaceHelper>([this](const Frame::Ptr &frame) {
//...
```

Where `Frame::Ptr` is just `shared_ptr<Frame>`. I don't like the idea of receiving a reference to a `shared_ptr`. For me, `shared_ptr`'s should always be passed as copies, so the lambda function owns a copy and if it takes too much time with it, it's guaranteed that the pointer owned by this `shared_ptr` will not die.

However I interpret the act of passing the shared_ptr as reference as this: "take this pointer, I do not want to own this anymore, you're responsible for it". So if the class that calls this lamnda funtion is not going to use it anymore, it passes as reference. However I think this is not how `shared_ptr` was designed to be used, and instead if the class wants to do that, it should **move** an `unique_ptr` like this:

```
viedoTrack->addDelegate(std::make_shared<FrameWriterInterfaceHelper>([this](std::unique_ptr<Frame> frame) {
//...
```

So, how would you design this class's lambda function?

Answer (score 2):

> interpret the act of passing the shared_ptr as reference as this:
>   "take this pointer, I do not want to own this anymore, you're
>   responsible for it"

Your interpretation is wrong. It actually means, take this reference to shared_ptr, I don't care what you are doing with it and we -the owners will delete the resource when we are done, we don't care if you still need it or not.

As your class is going to not to use it anymore(perhaps destructed) you are in the potential danger(if there is no other owner) of having reference to nothing AKA a dangling reference.

Comment: That quote is a good description of moving a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: So you agree it's not good to do this? I don't think he will delete the resources, it will just let shared_ptr goes away after the lambda function is called, rigth? So if I do everything inside the lambda function, I do not need to worry about it being deleted after. am I rigth?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs shared_ptr cares only about the owners. If they die, the shared_ptr dies too. So it is not a good idea to pass by reference. If you want to give up the ownership use a unique_ptr and move it.